# ASP.NET MVC3: DisplayTemplates does not show model value (MVC3 Partial Page)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

For learning DisplayTemplates, I created a “String” DisplayTemplate as listed below. It is expected to append the word “Hello” after the model’s string value. But it is showing only the word “Hello”. How do we correct it?

Note: String.cshtml is added under Views\Contact\DisplayTemplates

```
public class Contact
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

CONTROLLER

```
public class ContactController : Controller
{

    // GET: /Contact/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        Contact myContact = new Contact();
        myContact.FirstName = "Lijo";
        myContact.LastName = "Cheeran";
        myContact.Age = 26;

        return View(myContact);

    }

}
```

Detail View

```
@model MyDisplayAndEditorTemplateTEST.Contact

<fieldset>
<legend>Contact</legend>

<div class="display-label" style="font-weight:bold" >FirstName</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstName)
</div>

<div class="display-label" style="font-weight:bold">LastName</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName)
</div>

<div class="display-label" style="font-weight:bold">Age</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Age)
</div>
```

Partail Page for String DisplayTemplate (String.cshtml)

```
<%= Html.Encode(Model) %> Hello!
```

---

@Darin. For the editor template, I used  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName). Still it is coming as a label as shown below. How do we change it to get it as a textbox?

Details.cshtml

```
@model MyDisplayAndEditorTemplateTEST.Contact

<fieldset>
<legend>Contact</legend>

<div>FirstName</div>
<div>
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
</div>

<div class="display-label" style="font-weight:bold">LastName</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName)
</div>
```

EditorTemplate

```
@Model TEST
```

DisplayTemplate

```
Hello! @Model
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<%= Html.Encode(Model) %> Hello!` is WebForms syntax. Make sure you are not confusing the 2 view engines. So put the following in your `string.cshtml` Razor display template:

```
@Model Hello!
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. One more question - How do I make similar thing for EditorFor? When I used the same, it is coming as label; not textbox.

Comment: @Lijo, you use `~/Views/Contact/EditorTemplates/String.cshtml` and then you use Html.EditorFor instead of Html.DisplayFor in your view.

Comment: Marking as answer since it address the problem originally posted. I have other problems as listed as separate entry here, below.